# Request Data from one API according to the data recolted on another API

Tags: javascript, api

I'm using two functions to get some data from an API :
The first one request the data for each cycle, the second check if the payment has been done for each cycle.

All the data are placed in a common table. It seems that my issue come from the fact that I use a function in another function. It the that the second function executes itself only after the first one is complete.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQOVVB?editors=1001

```
var obj, obj2, dbParam,dbParam2, xmlhttp, xmlhttp2, myObj, myObj2, x, y, txt, txt2 = "";
    obj = { table: "cycle", limit: 10 };


    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);  
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Get the value of the inputbox
    // KT1 adress for trial KT19www5fiQNAiqTWrugTVLm9FB3th5DzH54
    var KT1 = $('#KT1').val();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {



      obj2 = { table: "cycle2", limit: 100 };


      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        txt += "<table><tr bgcolor=#000000 color=White>"
        txt += "<th>Cycle</th>"
        //txt += "<th>Reward</th>"
        txt += "<th>Paid</th>"
        txt += "</tr>"



              // Get the data of every cycle using API 1
              for (x in myObj) {
                // force x to 11 to get the condition PaymentCycle = cycle
                x = 11;
                cycle = myObj[x].cycle;
                //balance = myObj[x].balance/1000000;
                //TotalReward = myObj[x].rewards/1000000;
                //stakingBalance = myObj[x].staking_balance/1000000;
                //Share = balance/stakingBalance*100;
                //DelegatorReward = Share*TotalReward/100;

                // create line of the table
                txt += "<tr>";
                txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + cycle + "</td>";
                //txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + Math.round(DelegatorReward*100)/100 + "</td>";

                // here the CYCLE CHANGE CORRECTLY from 106 to 87
                console.log("Cycle before function: " + cycle);

                //API2 request
                dbParam2 = JSON.stringify(obj2);
                xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();


                    xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if (this.readyState == 4 && (this.status == 200 || this.status == 0)) {

                      myObj2 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                      // ERROR HERE - ALWAYS GET THE DATA OF THE LAST CYCLE (87) instead of every cycle check with API1
                      // It seems that this fonction xmlhttp2 is executed only after xmlhttp is complete giving to cycle the last value of saved for cycle (87)
                      console.log("Cycle after function: " + cycle);

                       for (var y = 0; y < 30; y++) {
                              // Get the Paiement cycle which varies from 106 to 90
                              Block = myObj2[y].type.operations[0].op_level;
                              PaiementCycle = Math.round(Block/4096);
                              PaiementCycle = PaiementCycle - 6;

                              // If the Data entered in the input box = of the destination adress of API 2 and the cycle of API1 and API2 is the same then
                              // Here cycle is always = 87 (Last value of the API1 reading (before the function the cycle change from 106 to 87). 
                              // I really don't understand why
                              if (KT1 == myObj2[y].type.operations[0].destination.tz && PaiementCycle == cycle) { 
                                console.log("Get one");
                                console.log("Paiement Cycle : " + PaiementCycle);
                                Paid = "/////////////////" + myObj2[y].type.operations[0].amount/1000000;
                                console.log("Paid : " + Paid);

                                txt += "<td width=10% align=center>Paiement :" + Paid + "</td>";
                                txt += "</tr>";
                                // All the data saved during this function is saved after the execution or the boucle for(x)
                                console.log("Txt /////: " + txt);
                                      // document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = txt2;
                              } else {

                              }//

                        }
                     //return txt;
                    } else {
                      //console.log("Not Ok");
                    }
                    };
                xmlhttp2.open("POST", "https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/operations/tz1XynULiFpVVguYbYeopHTkLZFzapvhZQxs?type=Transaction&number=100", true);
                xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp2.send("x=" + dbParam2);


        }
       txt += "</table>";

        console.log("Txt 2 : " + txt);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

      }
  };

xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards_with_details/" + KT1, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
```

You can see here my codepen, you can easily see that my function xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() { only executes itself after xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { instead of after getting each data from the JSON file

Answer (score -1):

try to use JavaScript Promises.
A simple Promise is [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/promises-in-javascript-explained-277b98850de)

Comment: Yes it seems to be the solution to go but a I don't understand it ;(

Comment: tried it but still doesn't work ! I had a really hard time to try to understand promise ! Someone can highlight me ?

Comment: I tried too but for your logic it is confusing. I hope someone will answer you.

Comment: My idea is to create a Table :
The first API is used to complete the two first columns (Cycle, Estimated reward). Then I run a second API to check if a payment has been done for this cycle and store it in the third column.
So everytime that the data of one cycle, I want to run the second API to check if a payment has been done during this cycle.

Comment: The two API works correctly separately : 
API : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWPdrx (Get the data from one cycle)
API 2 : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVzOer?editors=1111 (Get the paiement for each cycle) 
I don't understand my logic seems right but Im not able to merge these two codes.

Comment: If someone can help me, I give a bounty of 25 Xtz (Tezos). Approx $25-30

Comment: I made a cleaner version of my Codepen and put some comments to help you to understand where i have some issue : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZOPVV?editors=1012